# cocos2d, Game Center Leaderboard not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, leaderboard

I'm having a problem getting leaderboards to show. I think I have it right but I get this error in the log

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x105e39c0>.
```

here's my code to show and hide the view

```
- (void)showLeaderboard
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {   CCLOG( @" leaderboardController ok...");
        tempVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];

        leaderboardController.category =     @"com.bluemesasoftware.housedefender.hightestscore";

    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [tempVC presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
}
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController  
{
    [tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    [tempVC release];
}
```

Comment: I was going to post something but i see you fixed the problem, for anyone else here is the link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28079

Answer (score 1):

```
[tempVC presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: NO]; 

[tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

don't add the view to CCDirector's openglview

i assume you have this code in your AppDelegate...if so do this:

```
[window.rootViewControler.view addSubview:tempVC.view];
```

instead of

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];
```

also..move this code before `presentModalViewController`